# How to use subcriteria in populate (for example : .populate('something',{select:[]})) in sails js

Tags: sails.js

`.populate('something',{select:[]})) in sails js .` for me its an ambiguous usage. Is there any alternate solution for the problem

I used select inside populate ... but it shows sub-criteria doesn't work in this version of sails

```
Banktransaction.find(newData).populate('project_id',{select:['project_name']}).exec((err,banktrans)=>{
                                    if(err){
                                        return res.json({
                                            error : err
                                            });
                                        }   
                                        if(!banktrans){
                                            return res.notFound();
                                        }else{
                                            return res.json({
                                                'responseType':"success",
                                                'responseMessage':"Banktransaction details founded successfully",
                                                'result': banktrans
                                            });
                                        }



                                });

//result

{
    "error": {
        "name": "UsageError",
        "code": "E_INVALID_POPULATES",
        "details": "Could not populate `project_id` because of ambiguous usage.  This is a singular (\"model\") association, which means it never refers to more than _one_ associated record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as the second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this association, since it generally wouldn't make any sense.  But that's the trouble-- it looks like some sort of a subcriteria (or something) _was_ provided!\n(Note that subcriterias consisting ONLY of `omit` or `select` are a special case that _does_ make sense.  This usage will be supported in a future version of Waterline.)\n\nHere's what was passed in:\n{ select: [ 'project_name' ] }"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your models and explain that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured it out by now, but `.populate()` is limited, and sometimes the documentation for sails is wrong. I wrote a helper specifically to populate based on 3rd-normal O2M/M2M association tables. My method also required model methods giving the basic config of each association's field name and a reference to its model class. It's NOT graceful, it's a separate query for each record, but perhaps some of the details of my approach may interest you:

My populate [helper](https://github.com/NathanHawks/FictionDB/blob/master/api/helpers/populate.js).

[Example](https://github.com/NathanHawks/FictionDB/blob/master/api/models/LocationCharacter.js) usage.